# imagemap restart button script

Tags: jquery, imagemap

I would like to ask how to set a restart button not for a game but for imagemap activity. The logic of the imagemap: black and white image is the original image. Once clicked on numbers the colored image is replacing the original image and it shows whether the clicked number/answer is wrong or right.

[image]

Now my question is: how to write a restart function which will bring the original (black and white) image back, when all answers are opened. The code that I am using for clicks is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#shape1').mapster({
    singleSelect: false,
    render_highlight: {
      altImage: 'images/binary_tree-00-00_color.png'
    },
    mapKey: 'color',
    fill: true,
    altImage: 'images/binary_tree-00-00_color.png',
    fillOpacity: 1,
  });
});
```

Thank you very much for your attention and help.

I've tried to put the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mamekay/9vphykzz/

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle example ?

Comment: here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/mamekay/9vphykzz/

thanks a lot!

Comment: I would really like to help and had hoped the JSfiddle would add more explanation but in fact it confuses me more. Please consider editing the question to make it more clear what you are asking about. You may then get some responses. See this link for advice on how to produce a good question.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

ok I have a working setup.I could not get the fiddle to work - some problem with the CDN for the imageMapper plugin. So what I see is the black & white image and as I move the mouse over the image I see the colour image areas appear - sometimes a red cross and sometimes a green tick. I found that the way to reset the image mapper as in the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.reset').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#shape1').mapster('unbind');
    imageBind();
  });

var imageBind = function() {  
  $('#shape1').mapster({
    singleSelect: false,
    render_highlight: {
      altImage: 'p2.png'
    },
    mapKey: 'color',
    fill: true,
    altImage: 'p1.png',
    fillOpacity: 1,
  });
}

  imageBind()

});
```

You also need to add the reset class to the button.

```
<button class="reset" onClick="">Restart</button>
```

What is happening here is that when the page loads the imageBind() function runs to set up the imageMapper. Then when the reset button is clicked the mapster unbind clears down the mapper then calls the imageBind() function to set it up again.

The [imageMapper docs](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html#rebind) are quite useful.

I think that was all you needed.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, for your reply. 

but now click on images/numbers doesn't work. I am sharing the code https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxkQ17RZqAqLVkFpMDBRRklURTA. game.html is without restart button, and game_new.html is the new one, which is not working when we click on numbers.